# A function that checks if a string subnet mask is valid

Tags: c, linux

I've written a small helper function that receives a string and checks if it translates to a valid subnet mask value (`255.255.255.0` for example).

I would appreciate some peer review!

```
static bool isValidSubnetMask(IN char *subNetMask)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    char *endptr;
    int counter = 0;
    long int nChainInstance = -1;

    /*Check if string is valid*/
    if (!subNetMask || subNetMask[0] == '\0' || strlen(subNetMask) > 15) {
        return false;
    }

    /*Check string validity*/
    str = strtok(subNetMask, ".");
    while (str != NULL) {
        if (!is_numeric(str)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            /*Save number to be used as entry*/
            nChainInstance = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
            if (str == endptr) {
                /*Fail to translate string to number*/
                return false;
            }
            if (nChainInstance > 255 || nChainInstance < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        counter++;
        str = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }

    if (counter == 4) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your function considers any IPv4 addresses as valid, not just subnet masks. When visualized as 32-bit binary, a valid subnet mask has its n most significant bits set to 1, and all other bits to 0. Your function also accepts "holey" and therefore invalid subnet masks. See the [RFC 1878](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1878) memo for more details, including a table of all 32 possible subnet masks.

Comment: You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary `#include` lines, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It can really help reviewers if they are able to compile and run your program.  You seem to be missing definitions for `IN` and `is_numeric()`, and possibly others - including them may help you get a more meaningful review.

Comment: Ideally, you would provide a `main()` that includes your test suite of good and bad netmask strings.

Comment: @wingblade - you are right about "holey". I have a different function checking if the ip is valid or not

Answer (score 2):

**Missing includes**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
```

**Other test may be needed**

[@Wingblade](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190034/a-function-that-checks-if-a-string-subnet-mask-is-valid/190348#comment364528_190034)

**Non-standard function**

`is_numeric()` is not standard C library nor did I find it in Linux.

**Questionable signature**

I'd expect a function that checks a string's validity to cope with a `const char * subNetMask`.  So using `strtok()` on the supplied `subNetMask` is not possible.  Code needs to make a copy or otherwise assess the string.

```
// isValidSubnetMask(IN char *subNetMask)
isValidSubnetMask(IN const char *subNetMask)
```

**Weak functionality**

Below are 7 test cases that failed OP's code.  Sample working code provided.  `sscanf()` is a bit ponderous, yet useful as a test competitor.

```
bool is_numeric() {  // Added undefined Op's missing function.
  return true;
}

static bool isValidSubnetMask2(const char *subNetMask) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(subNetMask, "%*3[0-9].%*3[0-9].%*3[0-9].%*3[0-9]%n", &n);
  if (n == 0 || subNetMask[n]) {
    return false;
  }
  int i[4];
  sscanf(subNetMask, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &i[0], &i[1], &i[2], &i[3]);
  return i[0] <= 255 && i[1] <= 255 && i[2] <= 255 && i[3] <= 255;
}

void test(bool expect, const char *s) {
  char buff[99];
  strcpy(buff, s);
  bool y = isValidSubnetMask(buff);
  if (y != expect) {
    printf("Failed %d <%s>\n", expect, s);
  }
  y = isValidSubnetMask2(s);
  if (y != expect) {
    printf("Oops %d <%s>\n", expect, s);
  }
}

int main() {
  test(1, "255.255.255.0");
  test(1, "255.255.255.123");
  test(1, "0.0.0.0");
  test(0, "455.255.255.0");
  test(0, "255.255.255.-0");
  test(0, "255.255.255. 0");
  test(0, "2.2.5.2.3");
  test(0, "2.2.3");
  test(0, "+2.5.2.3");
  test(0, "A.5.2.3");
  test(0, "2.2.5.2.");
  test(0, "2..2.5.2");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Failed 0 <255.255.255.-0>
Failed 0 <255.255.255. 0>
Failed 0 <2.2.5.2.3>
Failed 0 <2.2.3>
Failed 0 <+2.5.2.3>
Failed 0 <2.2.5.2.>
Failed 0 <2..2.5.2>
```